# Want to change boot screen(with Samsung logo) appears before android animation in Samsung galaxy tab

Tags: boot

I am an beginner to android, but now i want to replace boot images like Samsung galaxy logo which appears during boot time in my Samsung Galaxy Tab. I have used many file managers like root explorer but then also couldn't find the exactly location of this boot screen(splash screen).

Even i have change boot animation by my created bootanimation.zip .But now please some one tell me that how to change this splash screen which comes before boot animation for just 2 seconds.

Every help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the other questions tagged with [tag:boot-animation]? Your question might already be answered.

Comment: Dear Al Everett, i have checked everything, but i am not talking about the boot animation, i have done it, But i am talking about simply two images comes before this animation(one is of Samsung Galaxy, and second is of operating system distributor Cyanogenmod)